# solc: exit status 1 when compiling my contract on my private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, console, compiler

I was trying to compile an example contract as told in the official website: [here](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter)

it was successful to setSolc and getCompilers ,but some errors occur when compiling the contract available on that website:

> var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'

undefined

> var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
>   Error: solc: exit status 1

```
at web3.js:3119:20
at web3.js:6023:15
at web3.js:4995:36
at <anonymous>:1:23
```

> greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
>   "contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }"
>
> greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)

Error: solc: exit status 1
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at :1:19

> var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)

Error: solc: exit status 1
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at :1:23

Answer (score 1):

check your compiler firstly.

> eth.getCompilers()

and then set Compilers by this way:

> admin.setSolc("/usr/local/bin/solc")

or add this option when you start geth

> --solc /usr/local/bin/solc